# include sourcemap in tree shaking for webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs, source-maps, tree-shaking

I have enabled tree-shaking on my module, but the source-map still includes the tree shaken code, even though the source does not.  Is there any way to have webpack remove the tree shaken code from the sourcemap as well?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with the latest webpack version. Did you find a solution for this in the meantime?